# RSS Reader works on LocalHost but not shared hosting

Tags: php, rss, shared-hosting

I have a simple PHP script that loads a RSS feed from craigslist. It has worked great for months, then all of a sudden a couple days ago it stopped pulling data. I tried running the script on my localhost and it works as it should. I reached out to GoDaddy who host the site with no luck. I tried another hosting service HostGator and same problem, it would not retrieve data.

What would cause this to stop working all of a sudden on a shared hosting account but still work on my LocalHost?

Here is the simple PHP script -

```php
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load("Craigslist RSS Feed URL");
$feed = array();
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $item = array (
        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('date')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    );
    array_push($feed, $item);
}

var_dump($feed);
```

Comment: Can you try adding a `var_dump(file_get_contents('feed url')` and `var_dump($rss)`?

Comment: var_dump(file_get_contents('url')) returns bool(false)

Comment: var_dump($rss) returns - object(DOMDocument)#1 (35) { ["doctype"]=> NULL ["implementation"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["documentElement"]=> NULL ["actualEncoding"]=> NULL ["encoding"]=> NULL ["xmlEncoding"]=> NULL ["standalone"]=> bool(true) ["xmlStandalone"]=> bool(true) ["version"]=> string(3) "1.0" ["xmlVersion"]=> string(3) "1.0" ["strictErrorChecking"]=> bool(true) ["documentURI"]=> NULL ["config"]=> NULL ["formatOutput"]=> bool(false) ["validateOnParse"]=> bool(false) ["resolveExternals"]=> bool(false) ["preserveWhiteSpace"]=> bool(true) ["recover"]=> bool(false)  etc..

Comment: Ok, that means that your server can't access that URL any more. Try adding this code, which will output more information for debugging: https://gist.github.com/atymic/4ca2d1ce823e2d5ec5d827f2b82ed0c5

Comment: Yeah that github example got me automatically blocked lol.. Whenever I try Curl it automatically blocks my IP

Comment: string(320) "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden Content-Length: 117 Set-Cookie: cl_b=kvpn3tGw6RG5KqJQDKcvJA0f-hs;path=/;domain=.craigslist.org;expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2038 00:00:00 GMT Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=86400 This IP has been automatically blocked. If you have questions, please email: ..

Comment: This test was done on a brand new hosting account and URL so it wasnt previously blocked

Comment: Oh, i'm not sure then. Is there a reason why the RSS feed is blocking IP addresses automatically?

Comment: Not sure but confused why it would work on LocalHost if that was the case, how else would anyone else use their RSS feed? Very confusing..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197105/discussion-between-atymic-and-ryan-d).

Answer (score 0):

Your Php script uses DOMDocument, which requires the php-xml extension. Do you have it installed on your shared host?.

I am not sure why your code works on localhost but not on the shared host. Perhaps your shared host ips are considered as suspicious by craiglist servers.

If your ip address is being blocked, then you may want to add user-agent headers to your curl request. This will make your request seem like it came from a web browser.

Comment: Thanks, that extension appears to be added by default on godaddy's server. Whats weird is it worked for months then all of a sudden it didn't..